# How do i prevent Prestashop from placing analytics cookies?

Tags: cookies, prestashop, analytics, webshop

I am setting up a Prestashop webshop.

When I check what cookies my shop uses I get (1) PHPSESSID and (2) Prestashop-* (iubenda).

The second one is an analytics cookie and by using it I will have to be able to make my user accept or decline the use of this cookie to comply with EU GDPR law.
I do not (want to) use cookies for analytics and it is therefore unnecessary to bother my customers with a consent banner.

I want to prevent my webshop from installing the analytics cookie.

I have uninstalled any module (that I could find) that had anything to do with user accounts.

Any solutions?

I have disabled modules concerning user accounts (those that I could find.)
I have tried searching StackOverflow and Google with different terms but only outdated answers come up.
Prestashops GDPR module didn't help (or maybe I didn't use it right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean installation of Prestashop will only save the ***"Prestashop-xxxx"*** cookie (containing encrypted information about the user's session) and ***PHPSESSID*** for the session.

Therefore, any other cookies that are written are certainly a result of third-party modules you have in place.

You can verify this by checking the modules integrated into the hookHeader especially.

To defer the loading of such a cookie, there are dozens of specific modules related to cookies and European legislation that allow you to postpone the loading of certain hooks until the policy is accepted. You can find them in official Addons, so I wouldn't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks! I think I misinterpreted the Prestashop cookie as an unnecessary tracking cookie, it seems like they are both necessary for the shop to work.